# How to get data from different SQLite tables and display it in one SimpleAdapter Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I am new to Android and need to display Starttime, Stoptime and Name in a Listview. For displaying I use a SimpleAdapter. The problem is that I have two SQLite tables:

**Table time:**
Starttime | Stoptime | Student ID

**Table student:**
Student ID | Student name

Right now, I use a **Cursor** to get Starttime, Stoptime and Student ID from my database

```
 Cursor curm1 = myDb.getAllMonday();
 while (curm1.moveToNext()) {
        final HashMap<String, String> resultMapMonday = new HashMap<>();
        resultMapMonday.put("Start", curm1.getString(3));
        resultMapMonday.put("Stop", curm1.getString(4));
        resultMapMonday.put("Student", curm1.getString(5));
        arrayListStudentsName.add(curm1.getString(5));
        listItemsMo.add(resultMapMonday);
 }
```

and then a SimpleAdapter to display it:

```
final SimpleAdapter adaptersimpleMo = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItemsMo, R.layout.timeslots_configurate,
            new String[]{"Start", "Stop", "Student"},
            new int[]{R.id.oneTime_start, R.id.oneTime_stop, R.id.selectedStudent});
```

But instead of the id, I want to display the names, which are stored in the other table. I can get the matching names of the Ids with another cursor

```
Cursor curm2 = myDb.getNamesbyIDs(arrayListStudentsName);
while (curm2.moveToNext()) {
        final HashMap<String, String> resultMapNames = new HashMap<>();
        resultMapNames.put("Name", curm2.getString(1));
}
```

But I don't know how to get the names in the same adapter to display the names in the same list Item as the matching start & stop time.

**EDIT**

```
  public Cursor getAllMonday() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_TIME + " WHERE day = 'Montag' ORDER BY CAST(start as unsigned)", null);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: its better to use JOIN in your query instead of getting it like this by pinging your database multiple times.

Comment: Post the code of `getAllMonday()`.

Comment: @forpas I did it

Comment: @FaisalNaseer can you tell me how to use the JOIN in my case? I don't understand it when reading to documentation... I guess I have not enough experience and knowledge for that

Comment: @forpas i have another question now: Default there is no name in the column name. If there is non, nothing will be shown, no start, no stop time. How do I fix this? I looked it up and found something with CASE IF s.name IS NULL THEN, but it didn't work yet... do you have any idea?

Comment: There should be some sql query written for your sql database can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `getAllMonday()` to use a query that joins the 2 tables:

```
public Cursor getAllMonday() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT t.Start, t.Stop, s.Studentname FROM " + TABLE_TIME + " AS t INNER JOIN " + TABLE_STUDENT + 
                 " AS s ON s.StudentID = t.StudentID WHERE t.day = 'Montag' ORDER BY CAST(t.start as unsigned)"
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return res;
}
```

Change the table variable `TABLE_STUDENT` and the column names that I used to the actual ones.
Now the cursor contains the name of the student and not the id.
Next change the code to:

```
Cursor curm1 = myDb.getAllMonday();
while (curm1.moveToNext()) {
    final HashMap<String, String> resultMapMonday = new HashMap<>();
    resultMapMonday.put("Start", curm1.getString(curm1.getColumnIndex("Start")));
    resultMapMonday.put("Stop", curm1.getString(curm1.getColumnIndex("Stop")));
    resultMapMonday.put("Student", curm1.getString(curm1.getColumnIndex("Studentname")));
    arrayListStudentsName.add(curm1.getString(curm1.getColumnIndex("Studentname")));
    listItemsMo.add(resultMapMonday);
}
curm1.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, I am one step closer, but get an error now "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Comment: You must change the column names: Start, Stop, Studentname to the actual ones in the tables.

Comment: I have one more question now: Default there is no name in the column name. If there is non, nothing will be shown, no start, no stop time. How do I fix this? I looked it up and found something with CASE IF s.name IS NULL THEN, but it didn't work yet... do you have any idea?

Comment: In which table there is no name? In the table students? If so change the INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: actually studentId of time table is NULL, thats why there can't be find any name in Students table

Comment: So in this case what do you want to display in the place of student's name?